Change event result
I am trying to launch a macro uppon the change of the value of a cell which contains a choice list and i tried first a simple change event to see how it works but nothing happens when i chose a value from the choice list:
Private Sub RunMacroForDropdown(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Synthese_Global As Worksheet
    Set Synthese_Global = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Synthèse_Globale")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Synthese_Global.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    Call MyMacro
    End If
     End Sub 
    Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "Cell B1 has changed!" 
End Sub

the code for the choice list is:
Dim str As String    'Create string of actual values

Synthese_Global.Range("B1").Validation.Delete
Synthese_Global.Range("B1") = Empty 
For i = 2 To Synthese_Global.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row   
If Synthese_Global.Cells(i, 1) = "N/A" Then 
    If Len(str) = 0 Then
      str = Synthese_Global.Cells(i, 1)
    Else
      str = str & "," & Synthese_Global.Cells(i, 1)
    End If   
End If 
Next i

Synthese_Global.Range("B1").Validation.Add xlValidateList, , , str



I updated with the code of the choice list

Your code only adds cells with "N/A" to the validation list?

Excel uses fixed method names for event handlers - you cannot invent a method name like RunMacroForDropdown and have it run automatically.

No it excludes "N/A" from the validation list

@Tim Williams: ok then what should I do then?

If you wanted to exclude "N/A" from the list, you'd use If Synthese_Global.Cells(i, 1) <> "N/A" Then

Step-by-step: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html#worksheet-change-event

yes it's <> sorry

You need to handle the Worksheet_Change event of the "Synthèse_Globale" worksheet:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, [B1]) Is Nothing Then
    Call MyMacro
  End If
End Sub 

Sub MyMacro()
  MsgBox "Cell B1 has changed!" 
End Sub



I tried this but nothing happens, it's the same when I change the value of B1

The "Cell B1 has changed!" message displays on "'Synthèse_Globale'!B1" changing. Be attentive to make the code.

Make sure your code is in the worksheet code module, not some other module...

@Tim Williams: I updated with my work module print screen, is it ok?

I think rotabor's screen shot clearly shows what code you need and where it needs to go.  Double-click "Sheet1" under "VBAProject" and paste the code above into that module.

@rotabor: can you please help? I updated with a print screen of my macros and I don't know if i'm doing something wrong, Tim has tried to explain but I didn't understand him I'm a beginner so sorry guys!

Double-click on "Sheet1(Synthèse_Globale)" and put the code there.

@rotabor: that works thanks ! I understand now that what you meant by "make sure the code is in worksheet module" :D one question please: can I call a macro which is in sheet1 from a macro which is in sheet2?

Yes, you can. Ensure no Private modifier. Also, you can put common subroutines and functions into a project module (Module1 on your screenshot).
